# Unable to access Chainlink Browser UI

Tags: postgresql, chainlink

Continue'd from another post. Some issues resolved but still cannot get into UI. Here's my stack..

Issues that I've come across were mainly bad password and username related. but I'm still getting the same result after making those corrections.

```
Last login: Wed Jun 23 14:32:13 2021 from 173.0.162.2

HVM@chainlink-kovan:~$ 
HVM@chainlink-kovan:~$ echo "ROOT=/chainlink
> LOG_LEVEL=debug
> ETH_CHAIN_ID=42
> MIN_OUTGOING_CONFIRMATIONS=2
> LINK_CONTRACT_ADDRESS=0xa36085F69e2889c224210F603D836748e7dC0088
> CHAINLINK_TLS_PORT=0
> SECURE_COOKIES=false
> GAS_UPDATER_ENABLED=true
> ALLOW_ORIGINS=
> DATABASE_URL=postgresql://chainlink-xx-xxxx:xxxxxxxx@10.xx.xx.x:5432/chainlink-kovan-db" > ~/.chainlink-kovan/.env
HVM@chainlink-kovan:~$ echo “ETH_URL=wss://kovan.infura.io/ws/v3/09a3ad081b05421b99a1dbc7671d41ce” >> ~/.chainlink-kovan/ .env
-bash: /home/HVM/.chainlink-kovan/: Is a directory
HVM@chainlink-kovan:~$ echo "DATABASE_URL=postgresql://chainlink-xx-xxxx:xxxxxx@10.xx.xx.x:5432/chainlink-kovan-db" >> ~/chainlink-kovan/ .env
-bash: /home/HVM/chainlink-kovan/: Is a directory
HVM@chainlink-kovan:~$ cd ~/.chainlink-kovan && docker run -p 6688:6688 -v ~/.chainlink-kovan:/chainlink -it --env-file=.env smartcontract/chainlink:0.9.4 local n
2021-06-23T16:28:15Z [INFO]  Starting Chainlink Node 0.9.4 at commit b7d22afdae61fc9146136e8518c221d406d10d6d cmd/local_client.go:51  
2021-06-23T16:28:15Z [INFO]  Locking postgres for exclusive access with 500ms timeout orm/orm.go:69           
2021-06-23T16:28:15Z [DEBUG] SELECT count(*) FROM "migrations"                  migrations/migrate.go:421 rows_affected=0 time=0.002135191 
2021-06-23T16:28:15Z [DEBUG] SELECT count(*) FROM "migrations"  WHERE (id = $1) gormigrate.v1@v1.6.0/gormigrate.go:389 rows_affected=0 time=0.001000931 
2021-06-23T16:28:15Z [WARN]  The file /chainlink/.env is not owned by the user running chainlink. This will be made mandatory in the future. cmd/local_client.go:179 
2021-06-23T16:28:28Z [INFO]  Unlocked account 0x5d1B0C6e8236e45A9eEf0F4f45B5C36E81f865aF store/key_store.go:74   address=0x5d1B0C6e8236e45A9eEf0F4f45B5C36E81f865aF 
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x28 pc=0xdba632]

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/store/models/p2pkey.(*Key).GetPublic(0xc0007a0000, 0xc0007a0000, 0xc00018de50)
    <autogenerated>:1 +0x32
github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p-core/peer.IDFromPrivateKey(0x1db17e0, 0xc0007a0000, 0x1db17e0, 0xc0007a0000, 0xc0007a49e0, 0x20)
    /go/pkg/mod/github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p-core@v0.6.1/peer/peer.go:237 +0x31
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/store/models/p2pkey.Key.GetPeerID(0x0, 0x0, 0x1d7b3a0, 0xc0006ea080, 0x1d7b3a0, 0xc0006ea080)
    /chainlink/core/store/models/p2pkey/p2p_key.go:53 +0x67
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/services/offchainreporting.(*KeyStore).Unlock(0xc00074f800, 0xc0004ec710, 0x9, 0x0, 0x0)
    /chainlink/core/services/offchainreporting/keystore.go:51 +0x395
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/cmd.TerminalKeyStoreAuthenticator.AuthenticateOCRKey(0x1d9e700, 0x2a95530, 0xc0000deab0, 0xc0004ec710, 0x9, 0x0, 0x0)
    /chainlink/core/cmd/key_store_authenticator.go:119 +0x70
github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/cmd.(*Client).RunNode(0xc0005d03c0, 0xc0000fcb00, 0x0, 0x0)
    /chainlink/core/cmd/local_client.go:70 +0x7d9
github.com/urfave/cli.HandleAction(0x15d90c0, 0xc00004af80, 0xc0000fcb00, 0xc0000fcb00, 0x0)
    /go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.4/app.go:526 +0xfd
github.com/urfave/cli.Command.Run(0x18425f5, 0x5, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc00000f5a0, 0x2, 0x2, 0x185b42b, 0x16, 0x0, ...)
    /go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.4/command.go:174 +0x58e
github.com/urfave/cli.(*App).RunAsSubcommand(0xc0007fc1c0, 0xc0000fc6e0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.4/app.go:407 +0x954
github.com/urfave/cli.Command.startApp(0x1840cf4, 0x4, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc00004b240, 0x1, 0x1, 0x18936cc, 0x33, 0x0, ...)
    /go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.4/command.go:373 +0x87f
github.com/urfave/cli.Command.Run(0x1840cf4, 0x4, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc00004b240, 0x1, 0x1, 0x18936cc, 0x33, 0x0, ...)
    /go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.4/command.go:102 +0xa28
github.com/urfave/cli.(*App).Run(0xc0007fc000, 0xc00011c060, 0x3, 0x3, 0x0, 0x0)
    /go/pkg/mod/github.com/urfave/cli@v1.22.4/app.go:279 +0x7e8
main.Run(0xc0005d03c0, 0xc00011c060, 0x3, 0x3)
    /chainlink/core/main.go:18 +0x65
main.main()
    /chainlink/core/main.go:12 +0x4e
HVM@chainlink-kovan:~/.chainlink-kovan$ channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 4: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
```

Comment: Thanks for making this. What happens when you try version 0.10.5 of the chainlink node instead of 0.9.4?

Comment: Different results with this version. But still can't get on UI. I'll post it below..

Comment: please check the password in the file specified by --password. You can add and delete OCR/P2P keys in the DB using the `chainlink node ocr` and `chainlink node p2p` subcommands: could not decrypt key 0x66666131336632336636316562613033366532343534346233306137626236333634366536653435636165613232323137386361656561643438386362313932: could not decrypt key with given password; could not decrypt OCR key bundle: could not decrypt key with given password

Comment: All of these basically are saying something is wrong with your password. Are you using different passwords at different places?

Comment: when I had the issue with the special characters i ended up changing my DB pass on g cloud.  but the only other password I have different is my google auth for the SDK.. I used the same DB pass when prompted to enter a new pass after starting the node... I'll probably end up starting all over.. need the practice anyway haha

Comment: Whats your password for your keystore? aka, the password that you created the first time you started the node?